# Java ExecutorService Read Tasks from Iterator

Tags: java, parallel-processing, executorservice

All,

I'm using a Java ExecutorService to perform tasks in parallel. Unfortunately, the list of tasks is now reaching the tens of millions. This means that submitting the tasks to the executor service ahead of time is infeasible due to memory constraints.

I am able to generate an iterator which dynamically creates the tasks as they are needed, but I'm not sure how best to apply this to the ExecutorService.

Should I create a task which pulls the next task from the iterator or is there some better way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using a BlockingQueue to put tasks into the ExecutorService? With those you should be able to lock your task-generating Thread until there is space again.

Comment: @daniu How is a BlockingQueue submitted to the ExecutorService? Or is it just used by the submitted runnables to read tasks?

Comment: It is used by submitted runnables.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking... Thanks.

Comment: You can try `Executors.newWorkStealingPool()` which use `ForkJoinPool`. I never used this, but I think you can combine this with scheduled task which check available resources for ForkJoinPool

Answer (score 1):

A quick experiment produced this that kind of works. It certainly should demonstrate one way of doing it.

I create and run a `ServiceFeeder` which delivers `Runnables` to the service via the `execute` method.

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

class ServiceFeeder implements Runnable {
    final Iterator<Runnable> i;

    public ServiceFeeder(Iterator<Runnable> i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            service.execute(i.next());
        }
    }
}

public void test() throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Hello world!");
    // Demo Iterator<Runnable> - use yours.
    Iterator<Runnable> i = new Iterator<Runnable>() {
        volatile int n = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return n < 100;
        }

        @Override
        public Runnable next() {
            return () -> System.out.println(n++);
        }
    };

    ServiceFeeder feeder = new ServiceFeeder(i);
    Thread feederThread = new Thread(feeder);
    feederThread.start();
    // Wait for the feeder to stop.
    feederThread.join();
    // Wait for the service to stop.
    service.shutdown();
}
```

This *kind of works* because it prints far more than I expected but that's not a problem as a demo IMHO.

Comment: @screenmutt - How is `service.execute(i.next());` not using an `ExecutorService`?

Comment: Ah! I missed that. Sorry. :)